# How to encrypt home folder after installing ElementryOS Loki

Tags: release-loki, encryption

I forgot to check for home folder encryption at the time of installation.? So is there any safe way to do that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First, install `sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils cryptsetup`. You'll need to encrypt your home folder while you are logged out,  so u need to change account-it has to be account with sudo privileges.

Login to the other account.

Then run `sudo ecryptfs-migrate-home -u user` and replace *user* with name of your account (the one that you want to encrypt).

Ta-da! Your home folder is encrypted. Afterwards:
1.Login to your encrypted account immediately. (Do not reboot before that!)
2. Click *Run this action * to create passphrase

In installation process system encrypts also your swap partition, so to encrypt it use `sudo ecryptfs-setup-swap`.

That's everything. :)